# Calling value from ajax to Django views

Tags: python, django, ajax

Im confused why it returns `None` when I print the value that comes from ajax, I used `request.POST.get("ajaxvalue")` to get the value from ajax requests but it didn't work, can anyone know what's the problem I encountered? it's very helpful for me.

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def updateStatus(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        taskId = request.POST.get('id')
        source = request.POST.get("sources")
        target = request.POST.get('targets')

        print(taskId); 
        print(source);
        print(target);
        return JsonResponse({'datas': 'test'})
```

**html ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  data: {
  id,
  'sources':0,
  'targets':1
  },
  url: "{% url 'updateStatus' %}",
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
})
  .done(function(data){
  console.log("success");

});
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('updateStatus/',views.updateStatus, name='updateStatus'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Why have you set `contentType: false`? Try removing this parameter

Comment: @Iain Shelvington thanks it works